# How to refactor recurring for loop?

Tags: java, refactoring, for-loop

I have a for loop which is used in many classes but the task inside the for loops are different. For example Class Foo uses following

```
for(Pojoclass a : listofPojo){
    if(a.getX().equals(b)){
        methos(a.getX());
    }
 }
```

and class Bar uses following:

```
for(Pojoclass a : listofpojo){
    if(a.getX().equals(x)){
        methos(a.getX());
    } // or some other logic
 }
```

I find many such loops in my project which iterate on same object but do different behavior. How do I re-factor this?

**EDIT :** I am not dealing with string, I am dealing with POJO classes

Comment: In general, you define a class to perform the "different behavior" and pass an instance of that class to the generalized function.  You can do this with explicit classes, but there are ways to do it with "anonymous inner classes" which are in some ways more elegant (though generally more highly obfuscated).  Of course all of the classes that do the "different behaviors" must be subclasses of a given class or implement the same interface, so that the common code refers only to one superclass/interface.

Comment: Surely you mean `a.equals(b)`? Unless, you really do desire to test for object-identity...

Comment: @mark Byers: do this is a method with parameter a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have the solution :) Whenever I hear '*different behaviour*' I think of the [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) straight away! 
I suggest you do the following:

```
public void forLoopReplacement(IActionStrategy strategy, IList<Pojoclass> projo){
   for(Pojoclass a : listofPojo){
      strategy.doActionOn(a);
   }
}

public interface IActionStrategy {
   public void doAction(Pojoclass param);
}
```

Any new behavior you define in your application can be encapsulated in a class that implements `IActionStrategy`.

I hope this helps.
Regards,

Comment: Whenever I hear 'different behaviour' I think lambda, function pointer, delegate, event, signal, continuation passing, policy. Right away. Oh wait, some of these even exist in Java

Comment: Agree, I was actually about to post a solution using Lambda Calculus but I went Strategy pattern instead. Many average Joe programmers do not event know what Lambda is. It is always better to suggest something that most of us understand without going Google for hours :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't refactor this kind of thing - it's already nice and tidy.

Refactoring is designed to replace redundant (duplicated) code that is the same but simply takes different arguments. In your case, the code is different, so you can't (and shouldn't) refactor it.

For example, if you were repeatedly turning byte arrays into hexadecimal strings, you should make a function instead of having the same code repeated everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) and it's `filter` and `transform` methods. First filter out elements that don't match the predicate and then apply a function to the remaining one's. It's a little bit more code but gives you much flexibility.

```
Predicate<Pojoclass> predicate = new Predicate<Pojoclass>() {
    public boolean apply(Pojoclass a) {
        return a.getX().equals(b);
    }
};

Function<Pojoclass, Void> function = new Function<Pojoclass, Void>() {
    public Void apply(Pojoclass p) {
        methos(p.getX());
        return null;
    }
};

Collections2.transform(Collections2.filter(listofPojo, predicate), function).toArray();
```

(Predicates and functions should be refactored nicely for reusage.)